# What is the difference between Levenshtein Automata and Damerau-Levenshtein Distance algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, levenshtein-distance

What is the difference between [Levenshtein Automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_automata) and [Damerau-Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) and when to use each algorithm?

Comment: Levenshtein Automate does not directly correspond to Damerau-Levenshtein Distance according to Wikipedia - it is about Levenshtein distance, which is similar but a bit different.

Comment: The Damerau Levenshtein distance, as opposed to the vanilla Levenshtein distance is the name to the edit distance that considers transposition of characters as a cost of 1. It does not describe the way to compute it.

Levenshtein automata is a way to compute an automaton out of a string, that makes it possible to compute its distance to other string very fast. It is limited in its answer (typically 0, 1, 2, more than 2). Lev Automata exists for Levenshtein Damerau distance as well.

Answer (score 3):

They are related but fundamentally different things. The Damerau-Levenshtein distance measures the "difference" between two strings. A Levenshtein automaton recognises strings that are of a certain *Levenshtein* distance ("difference") from a particular reference string.

So the automaton makes decisions based on the distance, while the D-L distance itself is just a definition of a particular measure of "difference" (and in fact, not the one used by the automaton).